# Run R function in bash loop

Tags: r, linux, bash

I have a script called `ggplot_cnv.R` containing serval functions.

One of the functions takes a file as input and outputs a ggplot2 plot:

```
plot.notch <- function(cnv_file, from=NA, to=NA) {
...
}
```

I would like to be able to run this on multiple files. I know that you can pass the file as an arg using `Rscript`, and then send it to the function within `ggplot_cnv.R`, but is there a way to do this without using args in my main script (`ggplot_cnv.R`)?

For example, how can I call the `plot.notch` function from the script `ggplot_cnv.R` in a bash for loop such as (this doesn't work):

```
for f in $(ls data/*.cnv); do
  Rscript -e "ggplot_cnv.R::plot.notch(cnv_file = $f)";
done
```

Comment: Maybe pass function name `plot.notch` and `$f` as arg, then use `match.fun` ?

Comment: Maybe without `commandArgs`, `$f` can not be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can use `R CMD BATCH` to do such work.

```
Usage:

     R CMD BATCH [options] infile [outfile]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`littler`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) program will provide the features you are looking for.  Several examples are provided at http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.examples.html